# Importing a csv to Active Record but adding an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question on implementing this in Rails 3.  I have been looking at the default CSV class as well as gems like csv-mapper.

When importing a csv the code looks like this

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    Product.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

But I would like to add an attribute to each record that is imported for example '000002' into the :account column.  How exactly would I modify the above to do that.  Sorry if this is an obvious answer I am still a beginner/intermediate (The most dangerous level ;-) in rails and ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value is static, then it's easy as pie:

```
Product.create! row.to_hash.merge(account: '000002')
```